Symless HDBs for KDB system
Has anyone came across kdb partitioned dbs without a sym file ?
Our use case requires an hdb which people can copy parts of it ( a few partitions here and there ) and use it in their own kdb systems.
I was thinking that I could replicate the structure of an hdb and each table partition to be a flat file.
/hdb/2001.01.01/table1
/hdb/2001.01.01/table2
/hdb/2001.01.02/table1
But this is no longer a partitioned hdb and most likely can't be treated as a partitioned hdb.
Another option I was thinking about was to cast all symbol columns to strings and keep a table in the hdb which indicates which columns should be symbol, allowing users to cast them back to symbol if they so require.

I think this is a bad idea for several reasons.
Rather than copying the data around, make the users query what they need and then if really required they can save it down.
However, I would rather recommend having one central DB and keep it as a traditional HDB with symbol columns and sym file. If they really need the data you can still sync it with rsync and an overnight job and include the sym file.

Thank you . I've explored many options, especially the basic ones. I particularly don't want people to have the sym file if they only get a subset of the HDB.  I was curious if someone had a similar use case.

@Alexander can you detail why you think this is a bad idea? It would improve your answer.

the sym file and enumeration is one reason why queries are fast. Converting everything to a string will not only make queries slower, but also use more disk space. Adding another table that keeps track of which column is a symbol complicates things unnecessarily. @flavio if you don't want others to have the sym file, then just make them query the data and enumerate against their own sym file/save to disk on their side. But why would you not want them to have a copy?
